# i cannot send attach in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

i have a error with my script, i need to make a query and save in csv, then send the csv in a mail.
im new in python so maybe it may not be the best way to do it , can you help me?
Heres the code

```
import csv
import pyodbc 
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEText




conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = conn.cursor()
query="select archivo_idreg,idtransferencia,montototal,c.diasremision idcliente_new,c.idcliente,c.razonsocial,t.fechadeposito from cdpnew..transferencias t left join clientes c on c.idcliente=t.idcliente/*and t.fechadeposito> {fecha} and t.montototal<>0 */where t.fechadeposito> getdate()-7 and t.montototal<>0"
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor:
    print(row)

# traer resultados
reporte = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y  %H-%M")
datos = cursor.execute(query)
csvsalida = open(reporte +'.csv', 'w', newline='')
salida = csv.writer(csvsalida)
salida.writerow(['ID', 'IDTRANSFERENCIA', 'MONTO TOTAL', 'ID CLIENTE NUEVO', 'ID CLIENTE', 'RAZON SOCIAL', 'FECHA DEPOSITO'])
salida.writerows(datos)
del salida
csvsalida.close()
conn.close()


msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'me@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'me@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email in python'
message = 'here is the email'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-relay.pagospyme.com',587)
# identify ourselves to smtp gmail client
mailserver.ehlo()
# secure our email with tls encryption
mailserver.starttls()
# re-identify ourselves as an encrypted connection
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('gmail-gmail.pagospyme.com', 'me@gmail.com')

mailserver.sendmail('gmail-gmail.pagospyme.com','me@gmail.com',msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()
```

And this is the error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'MIMEText' from 'email.mime.multipart' (C:\Users\zanag\anaconda3\lib\email\mime\multipart.py)

Comment: The correct import is `from email.mime.text import MIMEText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the import statement this way:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
```

Comment: Yes, thats works, now i have another problem,

Comment: File "C:\Users\zanag\Desktop\Trabajo\Scrips\PriReporte2.py", line 58, in <module>
    mailserver.login('smtp.pagospyme.com', 'password')

  File "C:\Users\zanag\anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    raise last_exception

  File "C:\Users\zanag\anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(

  File "C:\Users\zanag\anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 646, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)

SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')

Comment: It appears your login credentials for the SMTP server you are using may be incorrect. Double check the server name, user name, password, etc.

Comment: `SMTPAuthentication Error`. If you are sure that your login credentials are correct, you may consult the mail served settings provider by your host.

Comment: I solved it by changing the parameters for the variables, thanks aloot

Comment: `mailserver.login('gmail-gmail.pagospyme.com', 'me@gmail.com')`  shouldn't this be taking your login credentials as it argument? something like `mailserver.login( 'me@gmail.com', 'yourpassword')`